# Automated answer in django's makemigrations

Tags: python, linux, django

I want to automate the `python manage.py makemigrations` as in if a user encounters `Did you rename game.last to game.las (a CharField)? [y/N]` then the input will always be `y` but if the user encounters `You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'las' to game without a default` then it will automatically and continuously enter `1`.

I tried `yes | python manage.py makemigrations` as researched however this will just throw an infinite loop of `Please select a valid option` if the **default** input is asked

My desire is the automation between **1 and y value** as mentioned on my first paragraph or just throw an error if I input a wrong option on the **default input**

Comment: I'd highly discourage doing this... you'll more than likely end up with modifications to your data that might be hard to revert

Comment: @Sayse, but is it even possible?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? makemigrations is part of the development process, it's not something you want to automate.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, for continuous migration in my dockerized app in the cloud

Comment: Are you committing your created migrations? you should only need to do this step once in development anyway. I'd like to think its not possible but I'm sure it is with enough effort..

Comment: @Sayse, no I am not committing the migrates as it can be a conflict on the team development

Comment: But you don't run makemigrations "in the cloud", or in production at all. You run it *in development*, and commit the result.

Comment: Then thats the issue you should be addressing, you should definitely be committing them.

Comment: I plan to include the creation of migrations during the image build

Comment: That is wrong and dangerous. Once again, makemigrations is part of the *development* process, not the deployment process.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, can you suggest a way on how will I do a continuous change on my dockerized app in the cloud as it is in a ci/cd stack in docker cloud. So every commit of code, the migration files that are initially created will be gone on the newly created containers then after that; No changes are being executed anymore

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Your developers commit the migrations. Your CI/CD server runs them.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I don't think that will work fine on our process sorry. Is it possible for `makemigrations` to throw an error instead of an input when there is no default?

Answer (score 1):

First, run `manage.py makemigrations` locally. It makes a script to modify the database schema and that is part of development and places it in the `project/migrations` directory. Build the container such that the generated migrations are included in your Docker container (they should be automatically as they are part of the Django project source tree), and run `manage.py migrate --noinput` on start-up of the container. It will automatically apply any migrations that haven't been applied. Your migrations build up over time but you can squash them if you REALLY need to, I would recommend against it except rare circumstances.

This way, you will keep your development and production database schema in sync, and won't run into strange bugs because you generated new migrations on production that didn't exist in your development environment.

I would recommend purposefully designing your migrations so that they don't require any input on `manage.py migrate`. That is not always possible, for instance, stale models will sometimes require input and just be left there unless manually deleted.
Since all of the Django source is available to you, it's trivial to make a version of the migrate command that assumes y and place it as a management command. Then run that management command instead of migrate, done.
I would show an example of this but it is specific to the version of Django you are running.

Comment: is it possible to add the command `python manage.py migrate` inside the `migrations` folder? I have transformed a django app into a PYPI package and as soon as I pip install it I would like it implement the migration automatically in my local/producton project without the usage of a container. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the problem via `timeouts` like `timeout 30 yes | python manage.py makemigrations` so if in case an infinite loop via wrong option selection on non-nullable field input returns. It will automatically exit after 30 seconds. Giving me an alternative somehow to proceed my CI/CD without pushing my migrations